# SQL question conjunction

Tags: sql

Let's say you have a simple table with two fields: account and item:
An account can have multiple items.  For example:

```
Account    Item
11         Apples
11         Pears
11         Crackers
12         Apples
12         Bannanas
12         Cookies
13         Pears
13         Carrots
13         Apples
```

How would I write a query so that I could select all accounts with some specified set of items.   For example, how would I write  query so that I would select accounts where the fields are assigned both Apples and Pears (in the example accounts 11 and 13).

Thank you for your help.

Elliott

Comment: BTW: The term for this is [Relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could construct a query that will leave only the apples and pears in the set, then group by account and count the distinct items. If it matches the count expected (2 in this case) then the account has the full set.

```
select account
from tbl
where item in ('apples','pears')
group by account
having count(distinct item) = 2
```

Comment: +1 You seem to be the only one that actually understood what was asked

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT account From Table WHERE item in ('Apples','Pears')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-join to access information from two rows of the same table at once:

```
SELECT ai0.Account
FROM accountitems AS ai0
JOIN accountitems AS ai1 ON ai0.Account=ai1.Account
WHERE ai0.Item='Apples'
AND ai1.Item='Pears'
```

Comment: You are missing a `DISTINCT` or a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Only if completely identical rows were permitted, which would be an unusual approach IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this.

```
SELECT Distinct Account From MyTable WHERE Item = 'Apple' or Item = 'Pears';
```

This query will return a list of all the accounts, that have the item is apple or pears.  The Distinct ensures that each account only shows up once.