# Select name that contains ALL mentioned values and excludes duplicates in many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

I am fairly new to SQL and I am building a recipe database that takes in ingredients from a user and find recipes based on the ingredients.

I have an SQL query that gets recipe names that contain the ingredients, but I need it to select recipes that contain ALL the ingredients and excludes duplicates.

```
" SELECT recipes.Name, recipes.Preperation_Time, recipes.Author FROM recipes" +
" INNER JOIN RecipeIngredients ON RecipeIngredients.Recipe_ID = recipes.Recipe_ID" +
" INNER JOIN Ingredients ON Ingredients.Ingredient_ID = RecipeIngredients.Ingredient_ID" +
" WHERE ingredients.Name IN (" + ingredientString + ")");
```

Here are my tables if it helps:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[recipes]
(
    [Recipe_ID]        INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]             VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Instructions]     TEXT         NULL,
    [Preperation_Time] FLOAT(53)    NULL,
    [Author]           VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK.recipes] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Recipe_ID] ASC)
 );

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RecipeIngredients] 
(
    [Recipe_ID]     INT NOT NULL,
    [Ingredient_ID] INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Recipe_ID] ASC, [Ingredient_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RecipeIngredients_To_Ingredients] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([Ingredient_ID]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Ingredients] ([Ingredient_ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RecipeIngredients_To_Recipes] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([Recipe_ID]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[recipes] ([Recipe_ID])
 );

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ingredients] 
(
    [Ingredient_ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Ingredient_ID] ASC)
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like SQL Server code, _not_ MySQL.  Also, please read about how to use prepared statements.  Have you tried to solve this new query yourself yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL question conjunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752968/sql-question-conjunction)

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  I would recommend passing in the ingredients as a `VALUES()` list rather than strings.  However, with your construct:

```
SELECT r.Name, r.Preperation_Time, r.Author
FROM recipes r LEFT JOIN
     RecipeIngredients ri
     ON ri.Recipe_ID = r.Recipe_ID LEFT JOIN
     Ingredients i
     ON i.Ingredient_ID = ri.Ingredient_ID AND
        i.Name IN (" + ingredientString + ")"
GROUP BY r.Name, r.Preperation_Time, r.Author
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(i.Ingredient_Id);  -- all match
```

Comment: This query works if the number_of_ingredients is exactly the same as the amount of ingredients in that specific recipe, but once more ingredients are added, no results are shown. If all ingredients are selected, all recipes need to be shown but at the moment it does not.

Comment: @goldenpeng . . . I see what you are saying.  You want to count matching ingredients.